# Resizing multiple objects with cursor? [Illustrator]

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, illustrator-scripting

Does anyone know about a way within Illustrator (or a script from outside it) that could allow a user to **manually, with a cursor** resize multiple objects at the same time, while maintaining their distance from each other?

Basically, a 'Transform Each' tool that allows you to rescale multiple shapes in real time, as you would an individual shape (by clicking on a corner and dragging).

Instead of entering values, and clicking Preview for each new resize, you'd just click and watch them all resize as you drag the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Choose View> Show/ Hide Bounding Box and make sure Bounding Box is chosen to be on

Select your objects and Scale from a corner of the Bounding Box with the Shift key held down (Shift will keep scaling proportionate)

*This will scale all objects together but the distances between objects will also scale but it will stay relative to their original placement*

This will work the same with the Free Transform Tool (rather than the Bounding Box) and dragging from a corner of your selected objects

Comment: I think when you said *"distances between objects will also scale"*, this is precisely what the OP wants to avoid, if I'm reading the question properly. Not sure this is possible with click and drag scaling.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "drag" ability which maintains the Transform Each functionality as far as I'm aware.

All other scaling/dragging operations *will* scale distance between multiple objects as well as the objects themselves. Only Transform Each maintains positions.

(A script would't be any different. You'd still have to enter values, then see the change.. you'd actually *lose* the preview ability with a script.)

Comment: You can have preview ability in script.